# How to solve executing problem of MPICH: error code (10049)

Tags: mpi, mpich

I'm new to MPICH2 I trying to execute a little program. The program builds without errors but when I try to run it shows the error I've attached below. Could you please help me to solve this.

```
> [01:17268]..ERROR:Error while connecting to host, The requested address is not valid in its context. (10049)
[01:17268]..ERROR:Connect on sock (host=localhost, port=0) failed, exhaused all end points
SMPDU_Sock_post_connect failed.
[2] PMI_ConnectToHost failed: unable to post a connect to localhost:0, error: Undefined dynamic error code
uPMI_ConnectToHost returning PMI_FAIL
[2] PMI_Init failed.
Fatal error in MPI_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPIR_Init_thread(377): Initialization failed
MPID_Init(90)........: channel initialization failed
MPID_Init(357).......: PMI_Init returned -1
[01:10548]..ERROR:Error while connecting to host, The requested address is not valid in its context. (10049)
[01:10548]..ERROR:Connect on sock (host=localhost, port=0) failed, exhaused all end points
SMPDU_Sock_post_connect failed.
[1] PMI_ConnectToHost failed: unable to post a connect to localhost:0, error: Undefined dynamic error code
uPMI_ConnectToHost returning PMI_FAIL
[1] PMI_Init failed.
Fatal error in MPI_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPIR_Init_thread(377): Initialization failed
MPID_Init(90)........: channel initialization failed
MPID_Init(357).......: PMI_Init returned -1
[01:11576]..ERROR:Error while connecting to host, The requested address is not valid in its context. (10049)
[01:11576]..ERROR:Connect on sock (host=localhost, port=0) failed, exhaused all end points
SMPDU_Sock_post_connect failed.
[0] PMI_ConnectToHost failed: unable to post a connect to localhost:0, error: Undefined dynamic error code
uPMI_ConnectToHost returning PMI_FAIL
[0] PMI_Init failed.
Fatal error in MPI_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPIR_Init_thread(377): Initialization failed
MPID_Init(90)........: channel initialization failed
MPID_Init(357).......: PMI_Init returned -1
```

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int np;
int pid;
MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&np);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pid);
printf("Hi parallel...\n");
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you running the executable? Make sure you are using `mpirun`.

Comment: @ParthShah By using "mpexec -n 3 test.exe" command

Comment: @ParthShah when I use "mpirun" it shows this error "'mpirun' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: Please attach code and exact commands. And `mpiexec` is also fine.

Comment: @ParthShah I added the code into the question.

Comment: Maybe try uninstalling and reinstalling [MPICH](http://www.mpich.org/downloads/).